# The latest stable build (0.9.0) of A-Frame fails to animate cube compared to an earlier (0.5.0) release

Tags: animation, build, aframe

When I update the src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js" to the latest release 0.9.0 (src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js as per https://github.com/aframevr/aframe#builds), all of the animations fail to work. Does anyone know why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Animate - A-Frame</title>
 <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <a-scene>
  <a-assets>
   <img id="boxTexture" src="https://i.imgur.com/mYmmbrp.jpg">
   <img id="skyTexture" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/img/sechelt.jpg">
   <img id="groundTexture" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/a-painter/images/floor.jpg">
  </a-assets>

  <a-box position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2" src="#boxTexture" >
   <a-animation attribute="position" direction="alternate" dur="2000" repeat="indefinite"
      to="0 1.8 -5"></a-animation>
   <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="click" dur="2000" to="360 405 45"></a-animation>
   <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseenter" dur="300" to="2.5 2.5 2.5"></a-animation>
   <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseleave" dur="300" to="2 2 2"></a-animation>
  </a-box>
          
  <a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>
  <a-light type="ambient" color="#445451"></a-light>
  <a-light type="point" intensity="2" position="2 4 4"></a-light>
  <a-plane src="#groundTexture" rotation="-90 0 0" width="30" height="30"></a-plane>
  <a-camera>
   <a-cursor color="#ffffff"></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>
 </a-scene> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[a-animation has been removed in 0.9.0](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/releases/tag/v0.9.0). Use the [animation component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#sidebar)

Comment: For completeness, I have presented the working code for 0.9.0:                    <a-box position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2" src="#boxTexture" 
   animation="property: position; to: 0 1.8 -5; dur: 1500; loop: true; 
    dir: alternate"
   animation__1="property: rotation; startEvents: click; from: 0 45 45; to: 360 405 405; 
   dur: 2000; dir: alternate"
   animation__2="property: scale; startEvents: mouseenter; from: 2 2 2; to: 2.5 2.5 2.5; 
   dur: 300"
   animation__3="property: scale; startEvents: mouseleave; from: 2.5 2.5 2.5; to: 2 2 2; 
   dur: 300"
   ></a-box>